# Application of principle of argument

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let f holomorphic on a closed ball centered at 0 with a radius of R. Suppose f has no zeros on the boundary of the ball and has N zeros in the open ball. Show that $\max \operatorname{Re}(zf'(z)/f(z))≥N$, where the maximum is taken over all points on the boundary of the ball, namely for $|z|=R$.

I am really stuck in how to deal with the expression in the max sign. It seems that the problem is related to principle of Rouché but I am not sure.
Thank you for help!

Comment: You have$$N=\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_{\partial B_R}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz = \frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f'(Re^{it})}{f(Re^{it})}iRe^{it}\,dz.$$Now, take the real part and estimate.

Comment: Certainly... I think the last dz is dt, right? Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Yes, sure. I cannot edit anymore, though.